# indexing datetime column on a very wide table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, indexing, query-optimization

I have table with about 400 columns and 4 million rows in SQL Server 2012.
the only purpose of this table to be used by a reporting tool. this table is refreshed(dropped and recreated) every night via scheduled Job. so no update/insert/delete. 
there is a Date column with Datetime as datatype. I have created a clustered index on this date column but it only seemed to help a little.(there wont be any other conditions on where clause so I haven't included any other columns in the index)
the query send by reporting tool is like

select *(all columns listed)
from mytable
where date>='01/01/2010' and date <='12/01/2010'

it takes about 10 mins to retrieve all that falls under above date range which is about a million rows.

I need to get this under a minute if I can or the best I can.
if I can get some idea that might help me to achieve this . I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried following but no significant performance gain.
    -change datatype to 'Date'/'varchar'/'int' from 'Datetime'
    -create nonclustered index on same column
    -create clustered/nonclustered index including other columns to make it unique

Comment: Have you looked into the general performance of your server, e.g. using Resource Monitor? This may be a general performance issue: insufficient memory, not enough I/O bandwidth to the disk(s), ... . At least lock contention shouldn't be much of a problem if you are only running one report at a time.

Answer (score 0):

100 million rows may just plain be a data volume thing.
Try:

```
select count(*) from mytable where date>='01/01/2010' and date <='12/01/2010'
```

If that is fast then it is not an index issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. its not 100 million rows but about 1 million. I did the count(*), its instant.

Comment: 100 million or 1 million you don't have an index issue - it is the same where.   You have a data volume issue.